# Не отображается изображение в JSP

Tags: java, html, java-ee, jsp

В Java давно, а в Java EE совсем недавно. Разбираюсь в азах, так сказать.

Возникла проблема со вставкой изображения в .jsp. Перебрал все возможные абсолютные и относительные пути. Убил три дня на решение и всё впустую. В html всё работает, в jsp - ни в какую.

Дерево каталогов выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код index.jsp:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Attempt</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO</h1>

<div>
    <img src="/WEB-INF/pages/images/404.jpg" alt="Dafuq!" >
    <p><img src="images/404.jpg" alt="Here should be image!"/></p>
    <p><img src="images/up_background.png" alt="Here should be image!"/></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас spring mvc подключен?

Comment: @Виктор Да, конечно. В зависимостях Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя spring mvc можно в конфигурации использовать тег `mvc:resources` и с его помощью задать адрес для ресурсов.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/"/>
```

тогда на странице jsp вы можете обращаться по адресу /resources/ и дальше по структуре директорий:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/main.js" />"></script>
```

либо использовать `spring:url`

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/main.css" var="mainCss" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" var="jqueryJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/main.js" var="mainJs" />

<link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
<script src="${mainJs}"></script>
```

[Источник и пример](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема с jsp: вместо изображений квадраты ну и альтернативный текст.. Решение нашёл вот такое:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/1.jpg">
```

У меня картинки лежат в web/images.

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите папочку webapp на уровень src, lib, .idea. Затем вытащите все из папки WEB-INF, кроме web.xml, чтобы папки WEB-INF, pages и spring находились на одном уровне.
теперь прописываем путь относительно index.jsp

```
<img src="images/404.jpg" alt="Dafuq!" >
```

Comment: В таком случае мавен может не собрать проект, т.к. исходники он будет искать по адресу src/main/webapp  (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: Мб, но идеевский maven собирает именно по таким адресам(вместо папочки webapp - просто web), тогда путь который я указал в ответе должен сработать и в его случае, без перебутыривания папок

Comment: @Kotysh Хорошо, допустим. А в Eclipse такой трюк выйдет?

Comment: @Kotysh Хотя и в IDEA это всё равно не работает.

Comment: На счет eclipse ничего сказать не могу. А на каком сервере работаете? Tomcat?

Comment: @Kotysh Да, Tomcat 8.5

Comment: В папке с tomcat есть файлик catalina, в папку с этим файлом поместити кртинку, это корневой каталог. Соответственно и путь пропишите только из имени файла(404.jpg)

Comment: @Kotysh Нет, ну как способ, конечно, интересно, но не находите ли вы немного диковатым помещать файлы ресурсов в папку с сервером?
С учётом того, что на этом сервере ещё много чего будет запускаться, тестироваться.

Comment: @Bulbum конечно это дикость, тут и обсуждать не стоит :) Интересно было заработает или нет